# Calling custom function in bash results in "Command not found"

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying this to display a default helptext when no parameters are given when executing the script:

```
if [[ $@ ]]; then 
    do stuff
else displayHelp; 
fi

displayHelp() {
    echo "some helptext"
}
```

But for some reason, when executing the script on console, it says:

```
./myScript.sh: Line 48: displayHelp: Command not found
```

The same occurs when I call this function via `-h` parameter

Comment: If you want to check whether any arguments are given at all, it would be more idiomatic to use `$#` to check their count.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Functions must be defined before they can be used. So put the method before your call it:

```
displayHelp() {
    echo "some helptext"
}

if [[ $@ ]]; then 
    do stuff
else displayHelp; 
fi
```

or put your main code in another method and call this one at the end of your script:

```
main() {
    if [[ $@ ]]; then 
        do stuff
    else displayHelp; 
    fi
}

displayHelp() {
    echo "some helptext"
}

main "$@"
```